# Splitting large xml files in to sub files without memory contention

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML like following

```
<Jobs>
   <job>
   ....
   </job>
   <job>
   ....
   </job>
   ....
</Jobs>
```

Now what is best way to write each job node in a separate file without bringing the whole
file in to memory using xmlreader and xmlwriter or anyother options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create an XmlReader for the input file.
2. Position the reader on the first job element.
3. Create a subtree XmlReader using the [ReadSubtree Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree.aspx).
4. Create an XmlWriter for the output file.
5. Copy the contents of the subtree XmlReader into the XmlWriter using the [WriteNode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd6aw1b.aspx).
6. Position the original reader on the next job element, continue as with the first job element.
   Break if there are no more job elements to read.

Answer (score 2):

It's early days yet for XSLT 3.0 and streaming, but the following XSLT 3.0 stylesheet should do the job in Saxon-EE 9.4:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy">
<xsl:template match="job">
  <xsl:result-document href="job{position()}.xml">
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data really does look exactly as you described (including white space) then the best option would be to use StreamReader. It has a method to read to the end of the current line. You read lines until you get to `</job>`. Then flush that job and repeat.

Also, I don't think XmlReader is a bad option.