# Deeply control orchestration throttling and dispatching in BizTalk based on message batch size

Tags: biztalk

I have a biztalk orchestration which processes a single message. This messages are actually batches of messages. Most of the time, the batch size `n` is small (<1.000) but once in a while there are very large batches (>50.000). We have a high throughput of messages as well.

The orchestration takes a linear `O(n)` amount of system memory depending on the batch size and I know by observation that a single server can process up to an accumulated batch size of ~250k in parallel before it runs out of system memory and only returns `OutOfMemoryExceptions`. (Which will kill the BizTalk host instance and the orchestrations will startup on another host which will ultimately break again leaving our BizTalk group in a broken state which can currently only be recovered by manual intervention)

Small batches are common, large batches are rare but kind of deadly if there is more than one at the same time.

I know the batch size in advance so I could tell biztalk about it. But I see no way to interact with throttling. When throttling detects a lack of system memory it is already too late.

**Do I have to build my own queueing and dispatching on top of biztalk to achieve my goals?**

Our current solution is to use a semaphore with a value of 8 and every large message `n>1000` needs to get a semaphore slot before it is allowed to start processing. We had an edge case the other day where even this was too much. We reduced 8 to 4 to resolve this but now, we impacted the general throughput noticeably.

*Any idea or hint is welcomed!*

Comment: What exactly does the orchestration do? Is it only used for debatching?

Comment: technically it calls a .net component and has the message as an argument (as `XmlDocument`). It does all processing of the batch and all its contained messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `XmlDocument` within your processing.  It will further exacerbate your memory issues.  Prefer `XmlReader` for sure here.  However, I'd still try to move processing outside of your orchestration.  Even if you can get the streaming working in a .NET component called from the orchestration, you can still end up with an orchestration instance that runs for a long time and consumes lots of memory, which should be avoided whenever possible.  Therefore...
2. Avoid letting the orchestration get messages that large to begin with. It may be possible to debatch the message using the OOB `XmlDisassembler` if you can mark the schema as an envelope schema; if not, you may need to create a custom disassembler component to do your debatching (just remember to promote/write the proper context properties to the newly created messages from the original). If you use some streaming techniques (see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20375) in the pipeline, you can greatly reduce the memory footprint and have much greater control there.   Again, use `XmlReader` to actually parse and debatch the message (it shouldn't be super difficult - look into the `ReadToFollowing` and `ReadSubTree`, as in this [Splitting large xml files in to sub files without memory contention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806261/splitting-large-xml-files-in-to-sub-files-without-memory-contention)).  You might get away with doing this in an orchestration rather than a pipeline component, but in a pipeline component it should be easier to control memory usage.  You may also look into promoting things like a batch ID if you need to correlate the messages back together.
3. If you get a large batch, you will still need to throttle the number of concurrent orchestrations; you could do so as Richard Seroter suggests [here](https://seroter.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/biztalk-orchestration-throttling-pattern/), which uses multiple convoys that correlate on instance IDs to prevent too many from running at once.  Alternatively, you could use ordered delivery on the receive shape (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559637.aspx)), which would probably be my preferred option as it takes significantly less work and won't face the concerns around zombie messages that are possible with convoys.

Basically: try to think small and lean as much as possible and BizTalk will be happier.  BizTalk would much rather process 1000 small messages in a second than 1 very large message in a minute.

Comment: So in summary, you are telling me to redesign my process to better align with biztalk guidelines. thats okay and I will think about it. problems I know already: long running disassembler components are not visible as running processes in the administration console. and in my current implementation no single message is ever stored in the msgbox. we had this earlier and it is also some db load. what i take from your answer: there is no good/simple dispatcher hook for me to control throttling.

Comment: Not really.  If your disassembler is just debatching the message it shouldn't have to run that long.  And in BizTalk, evertyhing hits the message box ... unless your orchestration is triggered by a different message and directly is reading your large message without the help of the BizTalk infrastructure